# What does the regex (?<n>a)(b)\2(c) match?

Tags: .net, regex

What does this regex match?

```
(?<n>a)(b)\2(c)
```

It doesn't match `abc`, `abac`, `abbc`, `abcc`, or `ab\x02c` and it doesn't throw an exception.

---

If you take off the `(c)` it matches `aba`. My understanding is that unnamed captures get numbered first, and then the named captures. So `(c)` should get 2, except that I try to back-reference it before it's defined, so I thought maybe it would match `a` and `a` would get renumbered when it hits `c`, but that doesn't appear to be the case either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\2` in your regex refers to the `(c)` group, as your experiments have shown. Sadly, your regex never matches anything.

You can find reference in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx) <sub><sup>(though it isn't too clear, and seems to be followed by an unrelated example)</sup></sub>:

> If a group has not captured any substrings, a backreference to that group is undefined and never matches.

Comment: The example actually is related, but is indeed not very clear. Here's a better one: `Regex.IsMatch("ac", @"a(b)?\1c")`. This is `False`, whereas if you move the `?` into the `()`, it will be true. In the former the backreference is undefined, whereas in the latter it's an empty string, but they both match `abbc`.

Comment: Thus, that sentence doesn't exactly answer my question because it's referring to something a little different, but I think the result is the same. The backreference is probably undefined if it occurs before the capture group, and thus never matches.

Comment: Well, yes, that is better. The MSDN example doesn't even have a backreference, it just illustrates a failed group capture.

Comment: Fair point. It would answer if it said "If a group has not captured any substrings **yet**, ..."

Comment: This is still the most definitive answer, whereas everyone else was just speculating, so... thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

It matches "abbc" for me.  I am using Perl regex flavor and I get "a" as the group 1, the "b" as group 2 and the c as group 3. the \2 refers to the 2nd group which is "b"

`(?<n>a)`  - A named capture group: the name is "n" the regex is "a"
`(b)\2`    - Capture group matching "b" then a reference to the second group which is "b"
`(c)`      - third capture group matching "c"

Comment: Sorry, this is tagged `.net` because I want answers about .net regexes.

Comment: no problem.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html the unnamed capture groups get numbered first from left to right. so "b" is 1 "c" is 2 and the named group "a" is 3 that means in .net it should match abcc, however since the reference to the capture group comes before the actual capture it is null and hence fails. http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html edit: fails to match, its not invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

a's backreference is 'n'.  b's reference is '1' and the third is '2'

```
(?<n>a)(b)\1(c) matches abbc where n is a, 1 is b and 2 is c
```

it numbers unnamed back references with 1 and counts up.  Non-capturing parentheses are not numbered.  So, it can't match anything.

[Regular-Expressions.info on Brackets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Yes, and *then* named references get numbered too. `Regex.IsMatch("aa", @"(?<n>a)\1") == True`. You still haven't answered the question. What does `\2` match?

Comment: I believe that the second back reference which is definitely 'c' hasn't matched anything yet, which would be empty at the time of the evaluation, so the \2 won't match anything either, making the expression not match anything.